# jQuery callback into non-jQuery parent object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, settimeout

See this code:

```
var MyObject = new function() {

  this.tos = new Array();

  this.show = function() {
    this.clearTimeouts();
    $("#divExample").slideDown(null,function() {
      MyObject.tos[MyObject.tos.length] =
        setTimeout(function(){MyObject.doSomething();} , 1800);
    });
    return;
  };

  this.doSomething = function() {
    return;
  };

  this.clearTimeouts = function(){
    for (var i=0; i<this.tos.length; i++)
      clearTimeout(this.tos[i]);
    this.tos = new Array();
    return;
  };

}
```

MyObject and it's methods are used in a few places.  Maybe it's a bad way to do it, I dunno.  I didn't want to tie it too closely with jQuery for my own reasons, so leaving it like this made sense as I can easily change the slide to style.display.

The problem is that I dont like referencing the object as MyObject in the callback of the jQuery slide, but I have to to add the timeout reference to my array of them so they can all be cleared.  Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
this.show = function() {
    var obj = this;
    obj.clearTimeouts();
    $("#divExample").slideDown(null,function() {
      obj.tos[obj.tos.length] =
        setTimeout(function(){obj.doSomething();} , 1800);
    });
    return;
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var MyObject = (function() {

  // private variable
  tos = new Array();

  // private method
  function doSomething() {
       // do something
       // ..
  }      

  // return an instance with public methods
  return {
    show: function() {
      this.clearTimeouts();
      $("#divExample").slideDown(null,function() {
        tos[tos.length] =
          setTimeout(function(){ doSomething(); } , 1800);
      });
    },
    clearTimeouts: function() {
      for (var i=0; i<tos.length; i++)
        clearTimeout(tos[i]);
      tos = new Array();
    }
  }
}​;​
```